how to clip a part of picture
I drew a picture and planned to crop a small image from a certain area (e.g. white area). With everyone's help, I have found a solution, which is to first crop out a certain area and then draw the complete image.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[pattern=crosshatch] (0,0) rectangle +(6.5,4.5);
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}




@dozer Could you describe in more detail what you plan to do? It's unclear to me what to do now.
PS: If you simply want to insert the image shown here several times, just make a pic out of it...

Your edit is far from adding clarity…

It is not possible to know what you mean by "save it as another picture". You could take a screenshot, crop the image in a suitable program and save it as a jpg. That is probably not what you want. you could repeat the code, you could use spy, pic, clip or savebox - it all depends on what you really want.
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\fullname}%
\sbox{\fullname}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=crosshatch] (0,0) rectangle +(6.5,4.5);
\draw[fill=white] (5.3,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (3.5,2) -- (5.3,2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- (6,1.25) -- (5.3,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (3,1) rectangle +(3,2);
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt]{\usebox{\fullname}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: Just the white shape:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (5.3,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (3.5,2) -- (5.3,2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- (6,1.25) -- (5.3,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The shape filled with crosshatch:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=crosshatch] (5.3,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (3.5,2) -- (5.3,2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- (6,1.25) -- (5.3,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The same output, but with a clip:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[draw] (5.3,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (3.5,2) -- (5.3,2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- (6,1.25) -- (5.3,0.5)};
\draw[pattern=crosshatch] (0,0) rectangle +(6.5,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


thanks I need the part of the whole picutre covered by the white part.

I do not know what you mean

I have revised the question. maybe you can understand

Not really - it is still not clear what you try to achieve.

I need the part covered by the white area, not just fill with crosshatch in the white area

So you got it correct in your original code!

For what I understand, you can \clip your picture:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (2,.5) rectangle (5,2.5);
    % \draw[pattern= grid ] (0,0) - - (3,1);
    \draw[pattern=crosshatch] (0,0) rectangle +(6.5,4.5);%,pattern color=blue
    \draw[fill = white](5.3,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5)-- (3.5,2)--(5.3,2)
    {[rounded corners=6pt]--(6,1.25) -- (5.3,0.5)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}



thanks I need the part of the whole picutre covered by the white part.

@dozer try with \clip (3.4,.4) rectangle (6.1,2.1);

thanks for your reply. I don't need a rectangle, it is not a regular picture

You didn't make it clearer with your edit, you actually made it more complicated; by eliminating the code of this white partial area.
In the following I interpret the task as being about filling with the pattern=crosshatch; and the white area should not appear as an overpainting...
To do this you either need a closed path; or you can use the library fillbetween here.
In order to better see how the latter works, I made a \path (without draw and fill) from the unfilled / or unpatterned partial area (and the rest a little bit blue).
PS: clip was not needed here.

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween}% this...
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}% ...or that

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% filled part (with pattern)
\draw[% pattern=crosshatch % old
name path=A, 
thick, % optional
] (0,0) rectangle (6.5,4.5);
% unfillled part
\path[%fill = white, % not needed now
draw=none,% optional
name path=B
](5.3,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5)-- (3.5,2)--(5.3,2)
{[rounded corners=6pt]--(6,1.25) -- (5.3,0.5)};

% the wanted filling / pattern
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{pattern=crosshatch,% new
preaction={fill=blue!7}% optional
}; % new
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Is this not just an over complicated even odd rule?

I don't know what he actually wants to do.

What I mean is your output is just \fill[pattern=crosshatch, even odd rule] (0,0) rectangle +(6.5,4.5) (5.3,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (3.5,2) -- (5.3,2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- (6,1.25) -- (5.3,0.5)}; - pgfplots.fillbetween is meant for very different use cases.

@hpekristiansen Thank you for teaching me. ;)
